# How can I test that a method on an imported module is called during object construction

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-3.x, mocking, python-unittest

I'm working on a Reddit bot to learn TDD in python.

I have a module with a class that is something like this:

```
from praw import Reddit


class Bot():
    def __init__(self):
        self.reddit = Reddit(user_agent='myBot')
        self.reddit.login('fake', 'fakePassword')
```

In my test suite I have a setup method like this:

```
@patch('bot.bot.Reddit.login')
def setUp(self, mocked_reddit):
    self.mocked_reddit = mocked_reddit
    self.subject = Bot()
```

..and  a test like this:

```
def should_call_reddit_login_when_initialized_test(self):
        self.assertTrue(self.mocked_reddit.assert_called_with('fake', 'fakePassword'))
```

It seems like my patch is only partially working. It doesn't actually call the Reddit API which is good. The assertion is always false however.

```
line 22 in should_call_reddit_login_when_initialized_test
      self.assertTrue(self.mocked_reddit.assert_called_with('fake', 'fakePassword'))
   AssertionError: None is not true
```

Ideally I could just mock the entire Reddit class and assert the methods are called with expected arguments later. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: The fact that you *need* to reference an outside library when performing a *unit* test is indicative of a  design flaw. You should really think about changing your code so that unit tests really can be unit tests with no side effects.

Comment: I'm trying to mock it so that it isn't actually being called. I need to verify that it is called at some point, but I don't need the tests be calling the actual Reddit api.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are asking two different things:

1. Why my assert doesn't work
2. How can I mock entire `Reddit`

For *1* @wim answer is correct and tell to you exactly how to fix it: replace your test line by:

```
self.mocked_reddit.assert_called_with('fake', 'fakePassword')
```

`assert_*` mock's call already raise exceptions when assert fail.

To take care of *2* you should patch `'bot.bot.Reddit'` instead and take in account that your object will be the `return_value` of your mock. In this case I strongly recommend to use `autospec=True` to preserve `Reddit` complete signature, take a look to [Autospeccing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#autospeccing) to more details.

In this case your test become:

```
@patch('bot.bot.Reddit', autospec=True)
def setUp(self, mocked_reddit_class):
    self.mocked_reddit_class = mocked_reddit_class
    self.mocked_reddit = mocked_reddit_class.return_value
    self.subject = Bot()

def should_call_reddit_login_when_initialized_test(self):
    self.mocked_reddit.login.assert_called_with('fake', 'fakePassword')
```

In this case you should take care of use `self.mocked_reddit` to check object method and `self.mocked_reddit_class` to check both static and class methods. Follow a simple example:

```
import unittest
from unittest.mock import patch

class A():
    def b(self, a, b):
        pass
    @classmethod
    def c(cls,a,b):
        pass
    @staticmethod
    def d(a,b):
        pass

def ab(a,b):
    return A().b(a,b)

def ac(a,b):
    return A.c(a,b)

def ad(a,b):
    return A.d(a,b)

class MyTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    @patch(__name__+".A", autospec=True)
    def test_something(self,mock_a):
        ab(1,2)
        mock_a.return_value.b.assert_called_with(1,2)
        ac(1,2)
        self.assertFalse(mock_a.return_value.c.called)
        mock_a.c.assert_called_with(1,2)
        ad(1,2)
        self.assertFalse(mock_a.return_value.d.called)
        mock_a.d.assert_called_with(1,2)
```

Answer (score 4):

`assert_called_with` *is* the assertion.  As long as that isn't firing, i.e. raising an `AssertionError` exception, then you're OK.  You needn't check its return value, which will always be `None`.

Comment: How can I patch the entire Reddit object in my setup method?